# Can changes be evaluated for bound checkboxes?

Tags: svelte

In Svelte, you can bind the `checked` attribute of a checkbox. You can then [`observe`](https://svelte.technology/guide#component-observe-key-callback-options-) that bound value on the component, the callback of which provides the current and previous values.

However, when I try to evaluate changes in the state of a checkbox, the current and previous values seem identical. [Please see this example to illustrate the problem](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.25.0&gist=389c5a6d571ecad9ce529983c1732f8d). Have I done something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you haven't done something wrong — this is a quirk of how observers work, and the mutable nature of objects and arrays in JavaScript.

The observer is observing the *object* rather than the `checked` property, and the object itself isn't actually changing. Instead, you would need to observe `item.checked` directly.

That's not possible with the built-in `observe` method, but you can do it with `observeDeep` in [svelte-extras](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-extras/) — [here's a demo](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.25.0&gist=34d1428f9c9807cab0f8d0c2d4e5ecb0).

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Will these methods eventually be incorporated into Svelte itself?

Comment: No. The idea is that if you don't use it, you shouldn't have to pay for it — if `observeDeep` was a built-in method, every Svelte app would have to include the code for it even though few would need to use it. Putting these methods in a separate package means we can go wild adding lots of features (such as `tween`) that would otherwise be hard to justify.

Comment: Okay. May I ask what the costs of using these methods are?

Comment: Very small. You can [read the code here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-extras/blob/master/src/observe-deep.ts)